# How to set up Traefik v2 with gRPC and docker

Tags: docker, grpc, traefik

I have followed the instructions for the [TLS challenge](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-tls/) and read through the [grpc guide](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/grpc/) for traefik but I can't figure out how to put them together.

Currently I have the traefik dashboard at my domain working, and I could get a http server working, but I can't get the grpc service to be reachable. It shows up under HTTP Services in the dashboard, but when I attempt to hit the endpoint with a request it just times out saying it's unreachable.

my docker-compose (I don't have a TOML file):

```
traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.0.0"
    container_name: traefik
    command:
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.grpc.address=:8090
      - --providers.docker
      - --api
      # Lets Encrypt Resolvers
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.email=${EMAIL}
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.storage=/etc/acme/cert.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.leresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "/etc/acme/:/etc/acme/"
    labels:
      # Dashboard
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=websecure"

      # Auth
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=authtraefik"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.authtraefik.basicauth.users=admin:xxx"

      # global redirect to https
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"

      # middleware redirect
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxied

  grpc_server:
    image: xxx
    container_name: grpc_server
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.grpc_server.rule=Host(`grpc.${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.grpc_server.entrypoints=grpc"
      - "traefik.http.routers.grpc_server.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.grpc_server.tls.certresolver=leresolver"
    expose:
      - 8090 # grpc server
```

I don't need the layer from traefik to grpc to be encrypted which is why I haven't set up the self signed cert as per the grpc example. My grpc service is running in insecure mode and words when not behind traefik.

Anything obvious that I missed?

Comment: Bhavya Jain's comment from below translates to your example as adding a `traefik.http.services.grpc_server.loadbalancer.server.scheme=h2c` to your labels.  But even though I have such a statement in my own docker-compose I am still have the same issues as you do.  Did you ever figure out what was wrong in your case?  Might help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On gRPC endpoint please use scheme as h2c then traefik will work,

gRPC connection for example in YAML:

```
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - grpc
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: Host(`xyz.com`)
    services:
    - name: service_name
      port: 50051
      scheme: h2c
    tls:
      options:
        name: mytlsoption
      secretName: secret_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using port 8090 as entrypoint for grpc - in your docker compose file you don't map the port to traefik.
Assuming that you use port 80 to reach traefik it will result in a 404, if you use port 8080 it will be mapped to traefik, but traefik is not listening on that port and if you use 8090 the port is not mapped to a docker container, both resulting in a port unreachable error.